# Storing image url in firebase (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-redux

I'm working a side project using react, redux and firebase as backend.

Right now I was looking a way to store the URL of the image I was uploading into my firestore database along side other data.

This is what is working at the moment:

*Action addProduct.js*

```
export const addProduct = (product) => {
return (dispatch, getState, { getFireStore }) => {
    const db = firestore;
    const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${product.image.name}`).put(product.image);
    uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        snapshot => {},
        error => {
            console.log(error);
        },
        () => {
            storage
                .ref("images")
                .child(product.image.name)
                .getDownloadURL()
                .then(url => {
                    let updatedProduct = {
                        ...product,
                        image: url
                    }
                    db.collection('products').add({
                        ...updatedProduct,
                    }).then(() => {
                        dispatch({
                            type: ADD_PRODUCT,
                            updatedProduct
                        })
                    }).catch((err) => {
                        dispatch({ type: ADD_PRODUCT_ERR, err })
                    })  
                })
        }
    )
}
```

Couple of things bugging me here:

1. While it successfully uploads the image and stores its url in the database, this code looks really messy from my perspective. Can an action file be this complex? Is there a more cleaner way to do this?
2. My reducer is returning an *undefined* payload for some reason I can't find.

*Reducer productReducer.js*

```
import { ADD_PRODUCT, ADD_PRODUCT_ERR } from "../actions/types"

const initialState = {
    product: null
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ADD_PRODUCT: 
            console.log('Product Added', action.product)
            return state
        case ADD_PRODUCT_ERR:
            console.log('Product Failed', action.err)
            return state
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: "*Is there a more cleaner way to do this?*" - if you adopt async/await syntax, your promise chains and nested callbacks essentially go away altogether.  But what you are doing right now is not all that complex.

Comment: `dispatch({type: ADD_PRODUCT, updatedProduct})` will produce an action with `{ updatedProduct: updatedProduct }`, (in other words: action.updatedProduct ) but your reducer is logging `action.product`.

Comment: @rayhatfield So I should just change my state of my reducer to updatedProduct and action.product to action.updatedProduct, right?

Comment: You can change either end of it as long as the dispatch/action and the reducer are using the same field names. I'd recommend you change the dispatched action to use "product" as the key instead of "updatedProduct": `dispatch({ type: ADD_PRODUCT, product: updatedProduct })`.